# Efficient way to join on open interval (find "next" row in other df)

Tags: python, pandas, join

Say I have one dataframe of user timestamped events, df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        'id':1,
        'user_id':1,
        'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01'),
    },
    {
        'id':2,
        'user_id':1,
        'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-02'),
    },
    {
        'id':3,
        'user_id':1,
        'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-02-01'),
    },    
    {
        'id':4,
        'user_id':2,
        'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-01'),
    },    
    {
        'id':5,
        'user_id':1,
        'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-15'),
    },
])
```

and another table of another kind of event (e.g. a booking), df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            'user_id':1,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-02'),
            'booking_code':'AA1'
        },
        {
            'user_id':1,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-01-10'),
            'booking_code':'AA2'
        },
        {
            'user_id':1,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-03-10'),
            'booking_code':'AA3'
        },
        {
            'user_id':2,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2016-12-10'),
            'booking_code':'AA4'
        },
        {
            'user_id':2,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-03-10'),
            'booking_code':'AA5'
        },
        {
            'user_id':3,
            'time':pd.to_datetime('2017-03-10'),
            'booking_code':'AA6'
        },        
    ]
)
```

(Example dfs are long to demonstrate different cases)

What I'd like to do, is find, for each row in df1, the next event associated with that user from df2.

i.e. in words:
for user_id=1, time=2017-01-01: the 'next event' in df2 would be booking_code='AA1', time=2017-01-02.

So the result I'm looking for is:

```
    time_1      user_id     next_booking_code   next_booking_time
id              
1   2017-01-01  1           AA1                 2017-01-02
2   2017-01-02  1           AA2                 2017-01-10
3   2017-02-01  1           AA3                 2017-03-10
4   2017-01-01  2           AA5                 2017-03-10
5   2017-01-15  1           AA3                 2017-03-10
```

So far, the solution I've come up with is as follows:

```
#sort bookings by time
df2.sort_values('time',inplace=True)
#merge bookings with events, on user_id
df3 = df1.merge(
    df2,
    how='left',
    on = 'user_id'
)

#filter to bookings which are after the event
df3 = df3[
    df3.time_y > df3.time_x
]
#group by id to get one row per event
df3 = df3.groupby('id')
#get the first row for each event
df4 = df3.first()

#df4 is now the result we're after
```

Now, this works perfect on this toy dataset, but when the events data is ~10^6 rows, and this process just isn't working.

The other way I tried was doing it row-wise with `df.apply()`. Something like;

```
#use indexes for speedier retrieval
bookings = df2.set_index(['user_id','date'])
def get_next_booking(row):
    return bookings.loc[row.user_id].loc[row.date:].iloc[0].booking_code

df1['next_booking_code'] = df1.apply(get_next_booking, axis=1)
```

Which is also painfully slow on large data.

This feels to me like one of those occasions where there *is* a right way, and it's more performant, but I haven't found it, and I'm loathe to move this bit of the process to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a little pre/post processing to get exactly the output you want, but pandas recently (version `0.19`) added a new function `merge_asof` to efficiently to do these types of joins.  Docs here
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html

```
# `asof` field must be sorted
df1 = df1.sort_values('time')
df2 = df2.sort_values('time')
df2['next_booking_time'] = df2['time']

res = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', by='user_id', 
                    direction='forward', allow_exact_matches=False)

res.sort_values('id')
Out[29]: 
   id       time  user_id booking_code next_booking_time
0   1 2017-01-01        1          AA1        2017-01-02
2   2 2017-01-02        1          AA2        2017-01-10
4   3 2017-02-01        1          AA3        2017-03-10
1   4 2017-01-01        2          AA5        2017-03-10
3   5 2017-01-15        1          AA3        2017-03-10
```

Comment: This is perfect. I wasn't aware of this function! Thank you!

Comment: Just commenting again to say I tried this on the full data set (1.8M rows) and it worked almost instantly. This is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion to improve speed would be to set indices and sort them

```
df1.set_index(["user_id"], inplace=True)
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.set_index(["user_id"], inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
df3 = df1.merge( df2,how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: This would help, but when the data is really yuge, the grouping and filtering is also prohibitive.